# extjs sample code is not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 400,
height: 300,
title: 'Container Panel',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Child Panel 1',
        height: 100,
        width: '75%'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Child Panel 2',
        height: 100,
        width: '75%'
    }
]
});
```

The above code is not being executed... Can you please find the error or bug. I am very new to extjs. I found the above code while going through the [documentaion](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/layouts_and_containers)(check 'containers' Section). It is executing fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68rZT/) but not in my project.(other samples are working fine in my project).

ANSWER:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        layout: 'hbox',
        title: 'Container Panel',
        items: [
           {
               xtype: 'panel',
               title: 'Child Panel 1',
               height: 100,                
               flex:1
           },
           {
               xtype: 'panel',
               title: 'Child Panel 2',
               height: 100,
               flex:1
           }
       ]
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems:

1) You need to wrap the code in an onReady block.

2) The widths are not valid. How can both of them be 75%? In this case, you will want to use an hbox layout, with each child item being flex: 1.

Comment: I did what you mentioned.. I am not sure whether I did as mentioned but it is still showing blank page in chrome with no console errors. Please check my edited post..

Comment: Well, #1 you didn't put an hbox layout. #2 your onReady call is not correct. Look at any of the examples and you'll see why it's wrong.

Comment: I cant find any onready function here in documentation. I kept the `layout: 'hbox'`. Please show me a sample code..to understand the onready function.

Comment: Just lazy. Look at the code of any of the examples included with the SDK.

Comment: The layout hbox should be on the container, not the children.

Comment: Please be in touch.. I am beginner in extjs and I am in desperate need of support from extjs knowledge developers... (tried sencha forums, waste of time)

Comment: They aren't a waste of time, people expect you'll at least make a reasonable attempt before helping you. It's only fair.

Comment: Ya that's true, IMO, SO has best tools to get interact with programmers.. I created a room for [`sencha`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23760/sencha) now. :) I hope this will help beginners.

Comment: can you please come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23760/sencha .I have a doubt in documentation.